# Ruby on Rails in last version isn't working with Wicked GEM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, devise

I created a Ruby on Rails application with the version `7.1.3` and I'm trying to use the `wicked`gem with `devise` The sign-up process follows some steps to finish.

But after watching screencasts and following some articles, I have errors. Let's try to solve just one. The helpers that gem to redirect and render may not be working. Like I tried to use

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  steps :more_info

  def show
    @user = current_user
    @profile = @user.profile || @user.build_profile
    render_wizard
  end

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @profile = @user.profile || @user.build_profile
    redirect_to wizard_path(steps.first, profile_id: @profile.id)
  end
end
```

But I have an error in the rspec integration test.

```
NoMethodError:
  undefined method `wizard_steps' for Profile:Class
```

And also have something like

```
wizard_path
```

It does not exist. Is someone using this gem with rails? The repository of my application is

`https://github.com/rodrigotoledo/wallet_control`

I need to find the solution to sign-up process with steps using devise.

Comment: Can you include the entire stack trace for that error? It seems odd that it would be referring to `Profile`.